# Unapplying specific Django migrations went awry

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have two apps in my Django project. Foo and Bar. I have made some migrations for Bar and then decided to unapply them. And so I have 6 migrations for Bar and 10 migrations for Foo. `./manage.py migrate Bar 0004` - I'm rolling back to a migration #4. But it unapplies not only last two migrations in Bar, it unapplies also three last migrations in Foo. I noticed that those migrations have Bar 0004 migration in dependencies (except the last one):

```
dependencies = [
    ('bar', '0004_merge'),
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ('foo', '0008_auto_20150507_1303'),
]
```

Okay, they think they are dependent on Bar 0004 migration, but I don't unapply it. I unapply only 0005 and 0006. Why three last Foo migrations also get unapplied? What could be the reason behind such behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure they don't depend on Bar.0005 or 0006 (maybe indirectly)? Do you have squashed migrations? I'm not able to reproduce this behaviour, a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us help you.

Comment: No dependencies whatsoever, no squashed migrations either. I added a dependencies section from Foo migrations that were unapplied. Hope it helps.